# The solution of final value problem (parabolic) as a series in Fourier type by Matlab

Tags: matlab

**Problem:** In $L^2(0,\pi)$, $\langle a,b \rangle = \int_0^\pi a(x).b(x) dx$. Finding a function $u(x,t)$ satisfy 
\begin{align}
u_{t} - u_{xx} = F(x,t), \qquad  \Omega \times [0,T].
\end{align}
Dirichlet condition
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = 0, \qquad (x,t) \in \partial\Omega \times [0,T].
\end{align}
Final value condition
\begin{align}
u(x,T) = f(x), \qquad x \in \Omega.
\end{align}
Let $(x,t) \in \Omega \times [0,T] = [0,\pi] \times [0,1].$ And
\begin{align}
F(x,t) &= \dfrac{1}{6}\big(2t^3+9t^2+7t+1\big)\sin(x),\\
f(x) &= t \sin(x).
\end{align}
**The exact solution**
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}t^3+\dfrac{1}{2}t^2+\dfrac{1}{6}t\right)\sin(x).
\end{align}
**The solution as a series in Fourier type**
\begin{align}
u = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle u, \varphi_n \rangle \varphi_n,
\end{align}
where $\varphi_n$ is eigenfunctions, $\lambda_n$ is eigenvalues and
\begin{align}
&\varphi_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \sin(n\pi),\\
&\lambda_n = n^2,\\
&\langle u, \varphi_n \rangle = e^{(T-t)\lambda_n}\langle f, \varphi_n \rangle - \int_t^T e^{(s-t)\lambda_n} \langle F(s), \varphi_n \rangle ds,\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~= \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} e^{(1-t)n^2}\int_0^\pi f(x).sin(nx)dx - \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\int_t^1 e^{(s-t)n^2} \int_0^\pi F(x,s).\sin(nx)dx ds.
\end{align}
*Matlab's numerical solution does not converge to the exact solution?*

```
clf

clear 

Nx = 100;

X = linspace(0,pi,Nx+1);

dx = pi/Nx;

Nt = 100;

T0 = 1;

T = linspace(0,T0,Nt+1);

dt = T0/Nt;

t_ob = 0.2;

u_ex = @(x,t) ((t.^3)/3+(t.^2)/2+t/6).*sin(x);

plotu_ex = u_ex(X,t_ob);

F = @(x,t) (1/6)*sin(x).*(2*(t.^3)+9*(t.^2)+7*t+1);

f =  u_ex(X,T0);
```

Comment: do you have a question? where is the question?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot. Matlab's numerical solution does not converge to the exact solution. I tried to fix but failed